# DNS bind9 : can't see cache

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, cache

I am using seed Ubuntu 12.04 with two different virtual machines: the first is for a DNS server that runs BIND9 and the second simulate a user/client.

In the user machine i configure the primary DNS address to the address of the DNS server machine.

Well, this is the context of the `named.conf.options` file (location is `/etc/bind/`) :

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    //dnssec-validation auto;
    dnssec-enable no;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    dump-file   "/var/cache/bind/dump.db";
    query-source port 33333;
};
```

In the user I've tried to enter some different addresses with different host names (`google.com` , `cnn.com`, etc..) to see the impact in the cache file.

The problem: no matter what I do, the cache file is remain empty. Ofcourse I use the dump command:

```
sudo rndc dumpdb -cache
```

but still the file `/var/cache/bind/dump.db` is empty.
Thanks!

Comment: Are the permissions on the file set up correct?

Comment: Yes. We also tried to edit it with root permission but still the file is empty

Comment: Do note that it is `named` that writes the file, not `rndc` (important in terms of who needs write access). Also, unrelated to question, setting a fixed query source port is a terrible idea.

Comment: I changed the command with named and still the cache is empty..
The fixed source port: according to my assignment...

Comment: @AviadChmelnik What does it mean that you "changed the command with named"? What I meant is that it's whatever user that `named` runs as that will need filesystem permissions.  (As for the fixed source port, it has severe implications whether your assignment says so or not. Imo, you should question that assignment.)

Comment: Can you set forwarders, request google.com and do the same request running tcpdump on port 53, just to check if the cache is working.

Answer (score 0):

The file created is called `/var/cache/bind/named_dump.db`